# Dimension of convex polytope

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Hyperplanes, which are affine subspace of $R^d$ has a dimension of at most $d-1$.

For hyperplanes satisfying the equations:- $a_{j_1}x_1 + ... +a_{j_d}x_d = b_j ;\quad j = 1,...,m $ (1),

the dimension is given by $d - rank([a_{i_j}]),$ where $[a_{i_j}]$ is the matrix of the coefficients in (1).

Why is the dimension inversely related to rank of the matrix? If the number of independent equations are increased, why should the dimension of polytope decrease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension of the polytope is equal to the dimension of the nullspace of the matrix $A$ which you denoted as [a_ij].
Your polytope consists of all solutions to $Ax=b$, which can be desribed as $\hat{x} = x_p + x_h$, where $x_p$ is some constant vector for which holds $Ax_p = b$ and $x_h \in \mathrm{nullspace}\left(A\right)$. Thus, the dimension of your polytope is equal to the dimension $\mathrm{nul}(A)$ of the nullspace of $A$. 
Using the rank-nullity theorem (see [Rank-Nullity-Theorem][1]) you have in your case
$\mathrm{nul}(A) = d-\mathrm{rank}(A)$ and therefore this is the dimension of your polytope.

Comment: Thank you, Dimitar. I just didn't know what to look for. Rank-Nullity Theorem was my answer.

Comment: Glad, I could help :)